# change image with OnClick

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, imagebutton

I need some help,
I have one ImageButton that plays and stops a tune, I want the button to change to a stop symbol when playing and then back to a play symbol when stopped. So far I have the symbol and tune playing when the ImageButton is clicked the first time, but when it is clicked the second time, the tune stops but the image does not change, any advice?

```
mPlayTune.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (tuneMp.isPlaying()) {
                tuneMp.stop();
                tuneMp.prepareAsync();
mPlayTune.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_av_play_arrow);
            }else
                tuneMp.start();
                mPlayTune.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_av_stop);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just make 2 objects and hide or show them by clicking them? It's not a clean implementation but for sure a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, it was simply changing

```
                tuneMp.start();
            mPlayTune.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_av_stop);
```

to

```
 mPlayTune.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_av_stop);
tuneMp.start();
```

this way it sets the icon before hitting `tuneMp.start();`